# How to optimize mysql not exists query

Tags: mysql

I need help with a very slow running query (1/2 hr on 8 GB RAM lap top and query still not returning)

the trick is that I need to match on 2 values and the inner query needs one join:

```
t_outer  has 98,229 rows
t1_inner has 256,394 rows
t2_inner has 261,067 rows
```

query:

```
select product
from t_outer 
where not exists (select 1 
from t1_inner 
join t2_inner on t2_inner.pk = t1_inner.pk
where 
t_outer.code1 != t1_inner.code1
and t_outer.code2 != t2_inner.code2);
```

I have tried adding not null constraints on all `t1_inner.code1` and `t1_inner.code2`
and `t_outer.code2` and `t2_inner.code2.`  doesn't help.  there are indexes on all join fields as well as the code fields `(innodb, btree)`

here is explain plan, only three rows, but broken out for readability:

```
| id | select_type        | table | type  
|  1 | PRIMARY            | imp   | index 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pr    | range 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p     | ref   

| possible_keys                                  
| PRIMARY,tom2,tom3 
| PIDX_1055,tom1     
| CODEVERSIONIDX_1,PK_7619F05CE21,PRODUCT_CODE_1 

| key            | key_len | ref                      
| tom3           | 42      | NULL  
| PIDX_1055      | 9       | NULL  
| PK_7619F05CE21 | 8       | bds.pr.P_PRODUCT 

| rows   | Extra                              |
|  97470 | Using where; Using index           |
| 129573 | Using index condition; Using where |
|      1 | Using where                        |
```

thanks!

Comment: I assume there is an `AND` missing before `t_outer.code2 != t2_inner.code2);`?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: The names suggest it already, but are the columns `t1_inner.pk` and `t2_inner.pk` really `PRIMARY KEY`s in their tables (or at least indexed)?

Comment: edit fixed cars10.  and yes there are indexes on the pk's.  the table names in the explain plan map: imp -- t_outer, pr -- t2_inner, p -- t1_inner.  and on lines 2 and 3 of the explain, i can see that the indexes are being used.

Comment: actually -- correcting the error != should be = in the subquery (joining outer to inner) makes the query return in 2 seconds.  that might also be the performance issue....?